# Restart accessibility scanning when two fragments have views in the exact same location

Tags: android, android-fragments, accessibility

I'm currently optimizing my application for switch access accessibility. My problem is when I click on a view through switch access which starts a new fragment and this new fragment contains a view in the exact same position, the scanning of the views within the new fragment continues from that position. I proved that to myself by setting:

```
 android:layout_margin="1dp"    (or even px)
```

on the view I click. Now when I click it and the new fragments is visible the scanning stops and I have to press the button again to start scanning from the top left corner in the new fragment. That is the exact behavior as I want it but I don't think this is the best solution so I'm looking for something better than that. Any ideas for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [View::requestFocus()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#requestFocus()) to set the focus to the top element in the new fragment.